# python 3 mac: snappy.compress AttributeError: module 'snappy' has no attribute 'compress'

Tags: python-3.x, parquet

Has anyone solved the error: message: `compressions['SNAPPY'] = snappy.compress
AttributeError: module 'snappy' has no attribute 'compress'`
when reading parquet in python?  Btw, is there a way to read whole dir?

I am using `python 3` through `conda` on mac with `snappy` and `thrift` installed as per `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parquet`

code as follows:

```
import parquet
import json
import fastparquet

with open(data_in_path + "file.parquet/part-01snappy.parquet", 'rb') as fo:
for row in parquet.DictReader(fo, columns=['id', 'title']):
    print(json.dumps(row))
```

or

```
 df2 = fastparquet.ParquetFile(path).to_pandas()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was not able to find `snappy` solution, so I read data in `spark` with `snappy` and write it back with `gzip` after each no issue in python are found:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.option("overwrite","true").option("compression","gzip").parquet(dfWithGzip.parquet")
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

The reason was I installed the wrong python package. You should install `python-snappy` instead of `snappy`

In my case (os x), it was a simple, two step process:

```
brew install snappy
pip install python-snappy
```